# Can I minimize data used by my app by removing video?

Tags: android, audio

So I'm making an app that takes keywords from lyrics (say you've got a song stuck in your head that you don't know the name of) and searches for it online and then plays it on my phone (not marketing it, its just for personal use). I want to minimize data usage as I have a pretty low data limit, theoretically if I wrote code that strips the audio from any video I find would that reduce my usage or would it be the same?

Also, in the event that it still is the same, could I route the file through a domain that does the stripping for me and download from there?

EDIT: Is there a way to strip it as it downloads? i.e. isolating the audio component.

Comment: You would need a web server to do the stripping before passing it to your app. If you download the video, it doesn't matter what you do with it. You're looking at making your own web service.

Answer (score 0):

yes, if you remove the audio from the video, this will reduce the weight of the video.

> Also, in the event that it still is the same, could I route the file through a domain that does the stripping for me and download from there?

YES.